# /home/*********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04

While I was running my rails app this line suddenly pops up?

/home/********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems

Yes. I can run the app but is this problem normal?

I am using Rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.5.OpO.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this app is running on Linux with strange line ending. It will be all right in most cases.

Comment: but not in all cases.

Comment: If you are worrying, convert it then.

Answer (score 0):

use RVM to switch to another version of ruby (2.4) just to see if that solves it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just a problem with the OS or platform for in my teammates machine which uses Windows there is no problem. Thank you

Edit:. I have found out the real problem. My other teammates are using a different version of Ruby. Now that I switched to the same version as them the error has been gone. Thank you.