# warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems. rails aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I am setting up an existence Rails project using `rbenv` on Ubuntu 18.04. `rbenv` version is `1.1.2-11-gc46a970`. 
I have added `.ruby-version` file in the project root. When I run `rbenv version` I get the correct version of Ruby.

Now the issue is when I run `rails s` or `rails test:system` I get the following error:

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant URI::Generic
/home/my_project/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/my_project/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/my_project/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/my_project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/my_project/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/my_project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/my_project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

But I am unable to get any clue how to fix this (as I am new to Ruby Rails.)

**EDIT**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Dingoapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'London'

    config.serve_static_files = true

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post your config/application.rb codes?

Comment: @Fernand added the code from the required file.

Comment: Kinda of makes me think you got a windows version of ruby from rbenv:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713916/home-rvm-rubies-ruby-2-5-0-bin-ruby-warning-shebang-line-ending-wi
You may want to just see if you do get rvm and get the ruby version from there if it gives you the same problem. the \r mainly seems to come from windows if I am understanding correctly. This is pure speculation sorry. I know it doesn't make sense that ubuntu would get a windows version. Another possible answer is to uninstall and reinstall the ruby version and possibly even rbenv.

Comment: Can you change the line endings in the `application.rb` file to be Unix and not Windows?

Comment: @simonwo the shebang error is occurring in the ruby binary.  `application.rb` is kind of irrelevant. @ekr990011 has the right idea - something is really wrong with your ruby bin file. Either you have the wrong binary or accidentally changed the line endings of the bin file.